# How do I open a browser window/tab from blazor webassembly project behind code:

Tags: browser, blazor, webassembly, launcher

I'm converting a UWP app to Blazor WebAssembly with ASP.NET Core hosted.

I have my markup code in Index.razor and behind code in Index.razor.cs.

In the UWP project I opened a browser window from an onclick function like this:

var success = Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(targetPage);

What can I use in my Blazor project onclick event, that won't lead to "unhandled error has occurred"?

Comment: You'll need to use JS interop for this.

Comment: Maybe you can use a `<a target="_blank"` instead ?

Comment: these should be answers. For the js interop - window.open(url) is your friend.

Answer (score 15):

You can open a tab by making use of the 'window.open' function:

```cs
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime;
....
await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("open", $"https://www.mysite/mypage", "_blank");
```

if the page is internal to your website you can use the base uri:

```cs
@inject NavigationManager Navigation
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime;
...
await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("open", $"{Navigation.BaseUri}/mypage", "_blank");
```

Answer (score 2):

These are great answers and I took it one step further to make a re-usable component. My app uses anchors and link buttons so I have a quick-and-dirty switch for each.

**ExternalLink.razor**

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

@if (Type == "link") 
{
    <a href="" @onclick="OpenWindow">@(Text ?? Url)</a>
}
else if (Type == "button") 
{
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" @onclick="OpenWindow">@(Text ?? Url)</button>
}

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Url { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string Type { get; set; } = "link";

    private async Task OpenWindow() 
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("open", Url, "_blank");
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<ExternalLink Url="https://www.ourwebsite.com/" Text="Visit Us!" />
<ExternalLink Url="https://stackoverflow.com/" />
<ExternalLink Url="https://duckduckgo.com/" Type="button" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You case use below way

razor file

JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("OpenWindow");

html file

```
<script>
        function OpenWindow() {
            window.open('https://www.google.com', 'Test', 'width=800,height=860,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,location=no');
            return false
        }
        </script>
```

Answer (score -2):

Why not just use the build in NavigationManager?

```
Navigation.NavigateTo(a_url, true);
```

The trick is to use the force parameter.

Happy coding.

Comment: While NavigationManager supports redirect, it cannot open the URL in a new window.